# Sending commands to clients computer using sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I am fairly new to sockets in python and I want to know how i can remotely run commands to another computer. At the moment, I've looked a bit into sockets and I know how to send text messages across networks. And yes, I've port-forwarded my PC.

If this explanation is confusing, let me give examples:
When you

```
import os
```

in the python shell and use

```
os.system(<command>)
```

, it will run the specified command in your shell. I want to achieve that, but on a remote computer. I am able to establish a connection and I'm successfully able to transfer bytes over a WLAN.

Issue: I don't know how to send python commands via. sockets and I would like to learn how to do it. I know I could implement the code onto the client's connection side of things, but I don't want it hardcoded. I want something like a 'live terminal' of the client's computer allowing me to type commands in and watch them being performed remotely on the client's computer. I'd appreciate some help!

P.S. I'm using Python 3.7.4

Comment: *"I want something like a 'live terminal' of the client's computer allowing me to type commands in and watch them being performed remotely on the client's computer."* - this sounds like you want to implement a remote terminal similar to what telnet or SSH do. The main part in that is actually not the transfer of data (commands, responses) via sockets which you already seem to understand but the much more complex [terminal emulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) part. Due to the complexity involved in this the question is far too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do roughly the same thing you were doing with sending text messages. You must have had a client running your python script and your own computer(the server) running a script as well. The only difference between you sending a text message to the client and you sending a command would be in the python script the client is running.

In that python script, instead of printing the command to the console, you can just execute that command using `os.system()`

Comment: I see what you're saying, theres been a bit of misunderstanding. I'll reword my question.

Comment: I figured it out in the end, and I realised what you were saying. I also managed to get a terminal output sent back to the server. Thanks!